# Proving that a function is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove thatt $f(x) = x^2 \sin (1/x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$.

My attempt:

Let's extend our function $f$ to $[0,1]$ by defining thus
$$
\tilde f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2 \sin(1/x) & x \in (0,1] \\
0 & x= 0
\end{cases}
$$

$\color{green}{Claim}$: $\tilde f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

$\color{green}{Proof}$: Since, $\tilde f$ is same as $f$ on $(0,1]$, therefore is it is continuous on that interval.

For any $\varepsilon \gt 0$, take $\delta = \sqrt{\varepsilon}$, and thus
$$
|x-0| \lt \delta = \sqrt{\varepsilon}$$
$$
|x^2| \lt \varepsilon $$
$$
|x^2 \sin(1/x)| \lt |x^2| \lt \varepsilon $$
$$|\tilde f(x) - \tilde f(0)| \lt \varepsilon$$

Thus, $\tilde f$ is continuous at $0$, and hence it is continuous on the whole set.

> A function continuous function $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$, if and only if it can be extended to $\tilde f$ which is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Using the above theorem, we get that $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$ is continuous on $(0,1]$.

---

I have two questions to ask:

1. Is my proof formally written?
2. Can we do it in any other way? That extension theorem doesn't seem to be of my *taste.*

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. $|f'(x)|\le3.$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks fine. It might be helpful to mention
at the beginning that $f(x)$ is continuous over $(0, 1]$
since it is a product of 2 functions that are both continuous over $(0, 1]$.

The extension theorem seems to come from 2 facts:

1. A uniformly continuous function is continuous.
2. A function that is continuous over a compact set $S$ is uniformly continuous over $S$.

If you don't prefer using any of these facts, you can try proving straight from the definition of uniform continuity:

> Let $X, Y$ be metric spaces and $f: X \to Y$. $f$ is **uniformly continuous** if for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$, such that for any $p,q\in X$ with $d_X(p, q) < \delta$, we have $d_Y(f(p), f(q)) < \epsilon$.